# 100% header width not filling up 100% width?

Tags: php, html, css

I have a header and navbar (attached) then 2 input boxes below that. When I resize my screen to a smaller resolution, a scroller bar appears horizontally (which is weird as everything on the page is visible without scrolling), when I move this scroller bar, my header (with width 100%) cuts off and I just see the background underneath it. I have had this problem with multiple websites in the past, how do I fix it? My code is below.

assets/header.php

```
<html>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/blog/assets/bootstrap.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/blog/assets/style.css">
<head>

</head>
<body>
  <div class="header"><br><br><br>
    <p>My Blog</p>
  </div>
  <div class="topnav" align="center">
    <a href="/">HOME</a>
    <a href="./latest">LATEST</a>
    <a href="./all">ALL</a>
    <a href="./about">ABOUT</a>
    <a href="./about">SEARCH</a>
  </div>
```

assets/style.css

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Indie+Flower');
body {
   background-color: #D3D3D3;
   margin: 0 0 100px;
   font-family: "PT-Sans", sans-serif;
}

.header {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  background-image: url("./img/header-img.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100%;
  background-size:cover;
  background-position: center center;
}

.topnav {
    background-color: #333;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
}

.topnav a {
    display: inline-block;
    color: #f2f2f2;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 100px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 17px;
    text-align: center;
}

.topnav a:hover {
    background-color: #ddd;
    color: black;
}

.topnav a.active {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
}
.header p {
  color: white;
  font-size: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  font-family: 'Indie Flower', cursive;
}
```

index.php

```
<?php
include($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/blog/assets/header.php");
?>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
  <title>Create Blog</title>
<form action="send.php" method="POST" class="form">
<input type="text" name="title" placeholder="Title" class="input"><br>
<textarea name="blog-text" placeholder="Blog" class="input"></textarea>
</form>
```

style.css

```
.input {
  width: 50%;
}
.form {
  position: relative;
  left: 25%;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't need the php tag

Answer (score 0):

add this in your stylesheet to fill the header 100%

```
.header{
    width: 100%;
    margin-left: 0!important;
    margin-right: 0!important;
}
```

Comment: use ctrl+shift+R to reload the page after adding the above lines

Comment: I've tried CTRL+F5 which I believe also deletes cached files, so that's not the problem

Comment: Don't use !important in your CSS if at all possible. It causes more issues than it's worth. You shoud really use specificity to make selectors take precedence.

Answer (score 0):

Check if that css file is being accessed first. If so then have the following

```
.header {
    display: block;
    width: 100% !important;
    height: 200px;
    background-image: url("./img/header-img.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 100%;
    background-size:cover;
    background-position: center center;
}
```

If still not working add lines one by one and see the effect.

Let me know if you require any further help

Comment: It's definitely being accessed, I tried your code but it's not working. What do you mean add lines?

Comment: Turns out that if I remove the width 100%, it doesn't actually change the size of it

Answer (score 0):

```
.form {
    position: relative;
    /* left: 25%; */
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: form is a block element. which mean that - he has 100% width of parent, when you add "left: 25%" form move left - but width  remained the same

Comment: It stopped the overflow, but I mainly was focusing on fixing the 100% width for the header. Thank you though, upvoted.

Comment: or you can add 'margin: 0 auto; display: block'  to form elem (input, textarea)

Comment: can you give me a fiddle? I did not quite understand "focusing on fixing the 100% width for the header" ,or screen

Answer (score 0):

If the margin property has three values:

margin: 25px 50px 75px;
top margin is 25px
right and left margins are 50px
bottom margin is 75px

so change your body tag to remove the left and right margin, may be that is why the full width is not filled

Comment: Just messes up the header and moves it diagonally right

Answer (score 0):

i have tested this and it worked.when the size of explore become small without any horizontal scroll bar

```
<?php
include($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/blog/assets/header.php");
?>
    <style>
        .input {
          width: 50%;
        }
        .form {

          left: 25%;
        }
            </style>
        </head>
        <body>
        <continer>
          <div class="header"><br><br><br>
            <p>My Blog</p>
          </div>
          <div class="topnav" align="center">
            <a href="/">HOME</a>
            <a href="./latest">LATEST</a>
            <a href="./all">ALL</a>
            <a href="./about">ABOUT</a>
            <a href="./about">SEARCH</a>
          </div>
            <div class="form" style=" text-align: center;">
                    <form action="send.php" method="POST" class="form">
                    <input type="text" name="title" placeholder="Title" class="input"><br>
                    <textarea name="blog-text" placeholder="Blog" class="input"></textarea>
                    </form>
           </div>
        </continer>
        </body>
        </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

There's quite a few things that look wrong here, but I've shuffled your code into one document for testing purposes and it looks like the form is pushing over to the side, which is then making the page width wider, therefore allowing your header to go wider.

So you need to either remove the left: 25% from the form or make give it a width of less than 75%.

You need to be careful to maintain clean code, it looks like you'll end up with two 'head' tags from what you've posted, one of which is not needed and the other is not closed properly.